# Any easy way to specify default value of arguments in Python class constructor without writing inheritance?

Tags: python

Is there any easy to get a new class based on an old class which is just set some default arguments value of the old class? Code like this:

```
class DB():
    def __init__(self, ip, port, dbname, table):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.table = table

    def process(self):
        print self.ip, self.port, self.dbname, self.table
```

Now I need to get a set of new classes with some default values of `OldClass.a`, `OldClass.b`, `OldClass.c`, I will do like below:

```
class UserDB(DB):
    def __init__(self, dbname, table):
        OldClass.__init__(self, ip='user.db.com', port='1234', dbname=dbname, table=table)

class ProdDB(DB):
    def __init__(self, dbname, table):
        OldClass.__init__(self, ip='prod.db.com', port='1314', dbname=dbname, table=table)

class CommentDB(DB):
    def __init__(self, dbname, table):
        OldClass.__init__(self, ip='comment.db.com', port='1024', dbname=dbname, table=table)

class MeetingDB(DB):
    def __init__(self, dbname, table):
        OldClass.__init__(self, ip='meeting.db.com', port='8888', dbname=dbname, table=table)

userDB = UserDB('user', 'new')
userDB.process()
prodDB = ProdDB('prod', 'lala')
prodDB.process()
commentDB = UserDB('comm', 'gg')
commentDB.process()
meetingDB = MeetingDB('met', 'ok')
meetingDB.process()
```

I remember there are some tricks to simplify these child class verbosity codes. Any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you meant `NewClass3` and `NewClass4`, right? Furthermore: which verbosity do you want to remove? Do you want to automatize the change of the digit at the end of each argument, depending on the Class name?

Comment: You make only instances of `NewClass1`. Also, redefining `NewClass1` three times does not make any sense because only the last definition will be available.

Comment: @Edouardb Thanks for the quickly answer and sorry for my bad description. Verbosity codes means the long child class definitions. I wander is there any simple way to define a new class without inheritance which is just modify some default value of its super class.

Comment: Why not just use factory functions to supply the defaults?

Comment: @MikeMüller Sorry, I have modified my descriptions.

Comment: Can you modify the class `DB`?

Comment: @mgilson Yes, factory functions is good for the demo case. But not I want here. I wander is there any simple way to define a new class without inheritance which is just modify some default value of its super class.

Comment: @MikeMüller No, I can't. `DB` is third-part code.

Comment: You say "without inheritance", but then also refer to a super class. You can't have one without the other. If you don't need separate classes, use `functools.partial`, perhaps. If you do need classes, what you have is probably about as good as you can get.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks Blckknght. Maybe I have mess up something in my memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call parent's class' `__init__` as you just want to set the values to the instance properties. You may simply do:

```
class DB():
    def __init__(self, dbname, table):
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.table = table
        self.ip = 'user.db.com'
        self.port = '1234'
```

I think it is much cleaner. In fact you do not need 4 child classes. You may do it within single class using parameter to differentiate the category of each db as:

```
class DB():

    # Database type configuration
    db_type_conf = {
        'user': {
            'ip': 'xx.xx.xx',
            'port': 'xxxx',
        },
        'comment': {
            'ip': 'xx.xx.xx',
            'port': 'xxxx',
        },
        'prod': {
            'ip': 'xx.xx.xx',
            'port': 'xxxx',
        },
        'meeting': {
            'ip': 'xx.xx.xx',
            'port': 'xxxx',
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, db_type, dbname, table):
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.table = table
        self.port, self.ip = self._get_port_and_ip_from_db_type(db_type)
        #                    return port and ip based on `db_type` ^

    @staticmethod
    def _get_port_and_ip_from_db_type(db_type):
       db_type_conf = self.__class__.db_type_conf[db_type]
       return db_type_conf['port'], db_type_conf['ip']

    def process(self):
        print self.ip, self.port, self.dbname, self.table
```

For creating the objects, you may simply do:

```
user_db = DB('user', 'user', 'new')
user_db.process()
```

Comment: This is indeed much cleaner, but it could lead to trouble down the line if the superclass constructor is changed to do anything more complicated than just assigning the passed-in values to attributes of the instance. So if you do this, I'd suggest at least leaving a comment in the superclass constructor as a reminder to any future coders who might modify it.

Comment: @DavidZ: I think you do not even need inheritance in this case. If I were you, I would have done it like I did in the edit that I just did

Comment: Yeah, I would probably use a factory function or some such thing too. My comment applies if you are doing inheritance for whatever reason.

Comment: Doesn't the second solution actually modify the implementation of the class `DB`? I thought this is not possible as it is third-party.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is an awesome thing:

```
class DB():
    def __init__(self, ip, port, dbname, table):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.table = table

    def process(self):
        print self.ip, self.port, self.dbname, self.table


class UserDB(DB):
    def child_func(self):
        print "We Dont share Email Ids :)"

a = UserDB("151.101.1.69", 1999, "UsersInfo", "user_log")
a.process()
a.child_func()


b = UserDB("151.101.1.69", 2001, "ClickInfo", "click_log")
b.process()
b.child_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve any problem with another level of indirection.;)
How about having another class in between `MyDB`?:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # for legacy Python


class DB():
    def __init__(self, ip, port, dbname, table):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.table = table

    def process(self):
        print(self.ip, self.port, self.dbname, self.table)
```

Add your class that overrides the `__init__()`:

```
class MyDB(DB):
    def __init__(self, dbname, table):
        super(MyDB, self).__init__(self.ip, self.port, dbname, table)
```

Now use with class attributes. These classes do not need an `__init__()` anymore::

```
class UserDB(MyDB):
    ip = 'user.db.com'
    port = '1234'

class ProdDB(MyDB):
    ip = 'prod.db.com'
    port = '1314'
```

Making two test instances:

```
user_db = UserDB('user', 'new')
user_db.process()

prod_db = ProdDB('prod', 'lala')
prod_db.process()
```

Output:

```
user.db.com 1234 user new
prod.db.com 1314 prod lala
```

This provides a rather declarative way of doing things.
It should pretty readable, especially if the classes `UserDB` and `ProdDB` don't have an methods.

Since `self.ip` and `self.port,` do not exist in the instance `self`, the search will proceed to the class attributes of the current class, i.e. `UserDB` if we work with `UserDB`.